# Python failing to import winregistry

Tags: debian, python

I'm trying to use `secretsdump.py`, which relies on `winregistry.py`.

The error I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "secretsdump.py", line 41, in <module>
    from impacket import version, smbconnection, winregistry, ntlm
ImportError: cannot import name winregistry
```

I've used `sys.path` to see where python loads files from and copied `winregistry.py` to some of these directories, which made no difference. I'm using Kali Linux, a Debian based distribution.

I've tried upgrading python, which had no effect.

What else could I try to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you install `impacket`?

Comment: @gnouc I installed python-all which I thought included impacket.

Comment: I don't think so. Try `pip freeze` then check impacket is installed. Otherwise, run `sudo pip install impacket`.

Comment: Well, I just installed it into a `virtualenv` right now from `pip` and python successfully loaded the `winregistry` module from `impacket/winregistry.py` file for me. In `/home/me/Documents/temp` I said: `virtualenv ENV --system-site-packages`, `source ENV/bin/activate`, `pip install impacket` and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`from impacket import version, smbconnection, winregistry, ntlm` in this case means from the package `impacket`, import the modules `version`, `smbconnection`, `winregistry` and `ntlm`.

This means you need *impacket*, the package, not *winregistry*, a submodule of impacket, on the path. Try putting the whole package on the path somewhere, or just putting the `impacket` package right next to the `secretsdumpy.py` script.

`impacket` can be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/impacket/source/browse/).

The python2 tutorial section on package imports [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

Comment: I've installed python-impacket on debian, it still doesn't find it. I checked out impacket via svn, renamed the directory from impacket-read-only to impacket in the same directory as secretsdump.py, it still can't find it.

Comment: I haven't used svn very much, but doesn't `checkout` get the whole repository tree, as seen [here](https://code.google.com/p/impacket/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk)? You would need to copy the `svn/trunk/impacket` directory to the same directory as `secretsdump.py`.

Comment: Also, have you tried just opening a python interpreter and running:
`import impacket` and then `from impacket import winregistry`

Comment: Another thing: Python has two major an mutually incompatible versions in use, python3 and python2. I think Debian's default python version is still python2, and a quick look at the code for impacket suggests it is also python2. You say you "upgraded to the latest python version", could you be using python3 when instead you should be using python2?

Comment: After I realized the error from checking out via svn and moved to the directory alongside my script it worked fine, thank you!